# Implement Soap request in blackberry Using Ksoap?

Tags: blackberry, soap, ksoap2, ksoap

I want to implemnt a soap request in blackberry using ksoap library.

The following code lines to required to implement it.  Can someone describe the terms **servicenamespace,servicemethode,soapaction** and **serviceurl** with an example?

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace, serviceMethod);

ht = new HttpTransport(serviceURL);

ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
```

Comment: If its a DotNet webservice means better try this method than Ksoap: [Consuming a .NET web service from a BlackBerry native application using the Java ME Platform SDK 3.0](http://whatpaulhaslearnt.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/consuming-a-net-web-service-from-a-blackberry-native-application-using-the-java-me-platform-sdk-3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial.

[KSoap Tutorial](http://devcentral.f5.com/Tutorials/TechTips/tabid/63/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/102/The-Minimum-Steps-to-utilize-KSOAP2.aspx)

While I realize it is not exactly what you want to know, it takes you step by step in making a simple SOAP request with the KSoap library while also explaining what each method does.

Furthermore, access the javadocs here if you want to know about particular methods/fields:

[KSoap Documentation](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/overview-summary.html)